# Store entity from session doesn't work => $em->persist()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

at first: Sorry for my poor english :-)

A beginner need help!

I have 3 entities/tables:

Tables:

```
contact_person
id, title, firstname, surname, adress_id

address
id, street, zip, city, country_id

country (fix values)
id, name, code
1, Austria, AT
2, Germany, DE
...
```

Entities:

```
/**
 * ContactPerson
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="contact_person")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class ContactPerson
{
    /**
     * @var integer $contactPersonId
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $contactPersonId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", columnDefinition="ENUM('m', 'w')")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="surname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $surName;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Trac\TracBundle\Entity\Address", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $address;

    ...
}

/**
 * Address
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="address")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Address
{
    /**
     * @var integer $addresssId
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $addresssId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="street", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $street;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="zip", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $zip;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Trac\TracBundle\Entity\Country", inversedBy="addresses", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $country;

    ...
}

/**
 * Country
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="country")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Country
{
    /**
     * @var integer $countryId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $countryId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $code;

    ...
}
```

1 Form:

ContactPersonType:

```
$builder->add('title', 'choice', array('choices'  => array('m' => 'male', 'w' => 'female')));
$builder->add('firstname', 'text');
$builder->add('surname', 'text');
$builder->add('address', new \myBundle\Form\AddressType(), array(
    'data_class' => 'myBundle\Entity\Address'
));
```

AddressType:

```
$builder->add('street', 'text');
$builder->add('zip', 'text');
$builder->add('city', 'text');
$builder->add('country', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'myBundle\Entity\Country',
    'property' => 'name'
));
```

CountryType:

```
$builder->add('country', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'myBundle\Entity\Country',
    'property' => 'name'
));
```

When i do a form-post the controller stores the request-data successfully in tables. **All works fine!**

ContactPersonController:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
if($form->isValid()) {

    $contact_person = $form->getData();

    $em->persist($contact_person);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Result in tables:

```
contact_person
id, title, firstname, surname, adress_id
1, Mr, Ted, Tester, 1

address
id, street, zip, city, country_id
1, myStreet, 12345, Berlin, 2

country
id, name, code
1, Austria, AT
2, Germany, DE
```

**PROBLEM:**

When i store the contact person-entities in session and call $em->persist() from another controller, the country-mapping failed:

ContactPersonController (store contact person-objects into session):

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
$session = $request->getSession();
if($form->isValid()) {
    $contactPersons[] = $form->getData();
    //Add to session
    $session->set('contactPersons', $contactPersons);
}
```

AnotherController:

```
...

if($form->isValid()) {

    $customer = $form->getData();

    //Customer
    $em->persist($customer);
    $em->flush();

    //Get contact persons from session
    $contactPersons = $session->get('contactPersons');

    //Save contact persons to tables
    if(is_array($contactPersons) && !empty($contactPersons)) {

        foreach($contactPersons as $key => $contactPerson) {
            $em->persist($contactPerson);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}

...
```

Wrong result into tables

```
contact_person
id, title, firstname, surname, adress_id
1, Mr, Ted, Tester, 1

address
id, street, zip, city, country_id
1, myStreet, 12345, Berlin, 3

country
id, name, code
1, Austria, AT
2, Germany, DE
3, Germany, DE <= Create a new row... BUT WHY??? it should reference the id 2 by mapping into address (country_id)
```

Thans for help,

gondor

Comment: No error is shown to you? It's weird as redbirdo's answers seems a good one (at least in the concepts)

Comment: There are no error messages . The storage process for contact person is successfully passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you store doctrine entities in the session they become detached from the EntityManager. You need to [merge](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities) any entities which are already in the database back into the EntityManager. Something like this (checking for null where necessary):

```
    foreach($contactPersons as $key => $contactPerson) {
        $mergedCountry = $em->merge($contactPerson->getAddress()->getCountry());
        $contactPerson->getAddress()->setCountry($mergedCountry);
        $em->persist($contactPerson);
    }
    $em->flush();
```

Comment: Flush should be called once or at the very least, not inside a loop. Let it live outside your `foreach`.

Comment: Hi redbirdo, 

thanks for answer, but the problem is not solved. A new record in country is created, after $em->merge(). 

dump($contactPerson->getAddress()->getCountry());

Country {#297 ▼
  -countryId: 2
  -name: "Germany"
  -code: "DE"
}

Comment: @Artamiel you're right of course - I wouldn't normally do that but I blindly copied the code from the original question. Oops.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I made a mistake - edited answer to correct.